# in odoo 10, how do i modify the POS to add a new header widget?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

Im trying to add a custom widget similar to `HeaderButtonWidget`, or `StatusWidget`, but im not able to do it yet:
my first attempt:

```
odoo.define('my_module.pos', function(require) {
    "use strict";    
    var chrome  = require('point_of_sale.chrome');
    var _t = core._t;
    var _lt = core._lt;
    ...
    var AltHeader = chrome.HeaderButtonWidget.extend({
        template : 'AltHeader',
        init: function(parent, options){
            options = options || {};
            this._super(parent, options);
            this.action = options.action;
            this.label   = options.label;
        },
        renderElement: function(){
            var self = this;
            this._super();
        },
        button_click: function(){ console.log("its a hit") },
        highlight: function(highlight){
        this.$el.toggleClass('highlight',!!highlight);
        },
    });
```

but  this is not working, and  HeaderButtonWidget is not returned by the main method of   point_of_sale/static/src/js/screens.js so according to this page:
http://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/pos/gui.html so using the screen widget extend is not possible, how do i do this?

EDIT:
Here is what i have attempted:

```
odoo.define('pos_widget_toggler.pos', function (require) {
"use strict";
  var PosBaseWidget = require('point_of_sale.BaseWidget');
  var core = require('web.core');
  var _t = core._t;
  var _lt = core._lt;
  var AltHeader = PosBaseWidget.extend({
  template: 'AltHeader',
  init: function(parent,options){
            this._super(parent, options);
            this.label = _lt('OFF');
            this.action= function(){
                // code will be here
                } ;
       },
    });

  return{
    AltHeader:AltHeader
    };
});
```

and  `pos_widget_toggler.xml`

```
    <templates id="pos_widget_toggler" inherit_id="point_of_sale.template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="AltHeader">
        <div class="oe_status">
            <t t-esc="widget.label" />
        </div>
    </t>
   </templates>
```

Im still not able to see anything,

Comment: Tell me what exactly you want to create? New screen or changes in existing screen?

Comment: Add a new widget next to the close and wifi button on POS.

Comment: You can refer reprint receipt module. From that you can get reference easily. Because they are doing similar what you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

To create new widget,

```
odoo.define('point_of_sale.chrome', function (require) {
"use strict";
  var PosBaseWidget = require('point_of_sale.BaseWidget');
  var AltHeader = PosBaseWidget.extend({
  template: 'AltHeader',
  init: function(parent, options){
    //Your code
       } 
    });

  return{
     AltHeader:AltHeader
 };
});
```

**your_custom_module/static/src/xml/file.xml**

```
<t t-name="AltHeader">
    <div class="oe_status">
        // Your code
    </div>
</t>
```

Add this template file in your manifest.

**your_custom_module/__manifest__.py**

```
'qweb': ['static/src/xml/pos.xml'],
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: how about  the template specification? i dont see an id to inherit just t-name

Comment: do i have to do it in point_of_sale.chrome? im working on a separate module.

Comment: Updated my answer, you can create new widget from your custom module.

Comment: please take a look at  my new EDIT, i tried  something thats failed, not sure how i deviated from your example, can you see something wrong?

Comment: remove `inherit_id` from `pos_widget_toggler.xml`. Did you add `pos_widget_toggler.xml` in manifest ?

Comment: Yes, its present.  On removing the inherit, i still dont see it.